# On the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(2-x)}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

When I found closed form of integrals $1$ and $2$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x  \tag{1}\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x  \tag{2}\\
\end{align}

I thought why not generalize this for any $ b \in (-\infty, 1]$ like this
$$ \mathcal{I}(b) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-bx)}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x  \tag{3}\\$$

Using differentiation under integral sign I got that,

$$ \mathcal{I}'(b) = \frac{1}{b^2+1} \bigg[ -\ln(1-b) + \frac{1}{2}\ln(2) - b\frac{\pi}{4} \bigg]  
 \tag{4}$$
Now after integrating [$4$] from $0$ to $y$ we get,

$$ \mathcal{I}(y)= -\int_0^y \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x^2+1} \, \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{2} \ln(2) \arctan(y) - \frac{\pi}{8}\ln(y^2+1) \tag{5} $$

I wanted to find closed form of [3] at $b=1/2$,

$$ \mathcal{I}(1/2) = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(2-x) - \ln(2)}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

from [5] I got,

$$ \mathcal{I}(1/2)= -\underbrace{\int_0^{1/2} \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x^2+1} \, \mathrm{d}x}_{\mathcal{J}} + \frac{1}{2} \ln(2) \arctan\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) - \frac{\pi}{8}\ln\left( \frac{5}{4}\right) \tag{6} $$

Now I have been struggling with $\mathcal{J}$. I have no idea how to find its closed form. I tried by substituting $x \to x/2$ then I got,
$$ \mathcal{J} = \int_0^1 \frac{2\ln(2-x)}{x^2+4} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
Now I am totally stuck at this one.... Series expansion is making it more difficult to evaluate.

I search on [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/) but couldn't find which can help me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives an antiderivative for $\frac{\log(1-x)}{x^2+1}$ in terms of dilogarithms, yielding a closed form for the general case. It's rather messy.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen $2$ can be done easily I don't think we need dilogarithms for that, just see $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2} dx$ to get an idea how to do for $\ln(1-x)$

Comment: I think that you cannot avoid polylogarithms.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yeah! Not I got he(Brevan Ellefsen) may be talking about indefinite integral of $\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}$

Comment: The integral from $0$ to $1$ is easy, but the antiderivative will require dilogarithms, as will essentially any other definite integral (by the fundamental theorem of calculus)

Comment: Hey @BrevanEllefsen have you understood the solution of Claude Leibovici? I don't know how he found right hand side of $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(a-bx)}{x+i} dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find helpful the following beautiful results from [**More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series: A New Collection of Fiendish Problems and Surprising Solutions (2023)**](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-031-21262-8), page $7$, which is the sequel of [**(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)**](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-02462-8):
$$\int_0^a \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\arctan(a)\log(1+a)-\frac{\pi}{4}\operatorname{arctanh}(a)+\frac{1}{2}G-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Ti}_2(a)$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{2a}{1-a^2}\right), \ |a|<1, \ a\in \mathbb{R},$$
where $G$ represents the Catalan's constant and $\displaystyle \operatorname{Ti}_2(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}\textrm{d}t$ denotes the Inverse tangent integral.

Following the pathway style you started with, if you have the case $\displaystyle \int_0^b \frac{\log(1+x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x$, where $b >1$, you can let the variable change $x\mapsto 1/x$, use that $1/b=a$, and reduce again all to the initial integral together with trivial integrals. That simple! (in the blink of an eye)

Also, the following forms are given in the second book mentioned above
$$\ \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-a x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\arctan(a)\log(1-a)-\frac{1}{2}\log(2)\arctan(a)+\frac{\pi}{8}\log(1+a^2)+\frac{\pi}{4}\operatorname{arctanh}(a)$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}G-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Ti}_2(a)+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{2a}{1-a^2}\right), \ |a|<1, \ a\in \mathbb{R}.$$
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+ax)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\log(2)\arctan(a)-\arctan(a)\log(1+a)+\frac{\pi}{8}\log(1+a^2)+\frac{\pi}{4}\operatorname{arctanh}(a)$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}G+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Ti}_2(a)+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{2a}{1-a^2}\right), \ |a|<1, \ a\in \mathbb{R}.$$

**End of story** (everything can be properly adjusted with a tiny bit of creativity)

Comment: Wow, this type of solution I was expecting. Thank you very much! Btw can you attach the link of **More (Almost) ....(2023)**? I couldn't find it :(

Comment: Nice to hear that! :-) I just updated the post.

Answer (score 5):

**Preliminary integral**
$$\newcommand{\Li}{\operatorname{Li}}\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-ax)}{x+b}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_b^{1+b}\frac{\log(1+ab-ax)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\
&=\log(1+ab)\log\left(\frac{1+b}b\right)+\int_b^{1+b}\frac{\log\left(1-\frac{ax}{1+ab}\right)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1b}\\
&=\log(1+ab)\log\left(\frac{1+b}b\right)+\int_{\frac{ab}{1+ab}}^{\frac{ab+a}{1+ab}}\frac{\log(1-x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1c}\\
&=\log(1+ab)\log\left(\frac{1+b}b\right)-\Li_2\left(\frac{ab+a}{1+ab}\right)+\Li_2\left(\frac{ab}{1+ab}\right)\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ substitute $x\mapsto x-b$
$\text{(1b):}$ apply $\int_b^{1+b}\frac{\log(1+ab)}x\,\mathrm{d}x=\log(1+ab)\log\left(\frac{1+b}b\right)$
$\text{(1c):}$ substitute $x\mapsto\frac{1+ab}ax$
$\text{(1d):}$ $\int\frac{\log(1-x)}x\,\mathrm{d}x=-\Li_2(x)+C$

---

**Integral in Question**
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\log(2-x)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac\pi4\log(2)+\int_0^1\frac{\log\left(1-\frac12x\right)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac\pi4\log(2)-\frac1{2i}\int_0^1\frac{\log\left(1-\frac12x\right)}{x+i}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac1{2i}\int_0^1\frac{\log\left(1-\frac12x\right)}{x-i}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac\pi4\log(2)\\
&-\frac1{2i}\left(\log\left(1+\frac12i\right)\log(1-i)-\Li_2\left(\frac{3+i}5\right)+\Li_2\left(\frac{1+2i}5\right)\right)\\
&+\frac1{2i}\left(\log\left(1-\frac12i\right)\log(1+i)-\Li_2\left(\frac{3-i}5\right)+\Li_2\left(\frac{1-2i}5\right)\right)\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac\pi4\log(2)+\Im\left(\log\left(1-\frac12i\right)\log(1+i)-\Li_2\left(\frac{3-i}5\right)+\Li_2\left(\frac{1-2i}5\right)\right)\tag{2d}\\
&=\frac\pi8\log\left(\frac54\right)+\frac12\log(2)\tan^{-1}(2)-\Im\left(\Li_2\left(\frac{3-i}5\right)-\Li_2\left(\frac{1-2i}5\right)\right)\tag{2e}\\[5pt]
&\approx0.33509279757101529304\tag{2f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ pull $\int_0^1\frac{\log(2)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac\pi4\log(2)$ out of the integral
$\text{(2b):}$ $\frac1{1+x^2}=-\frac1{2i}\frac1{x+i}+\frac1{2i}\frac1{x-i}$
$\text{(2c):}$ apply $(1)$
$\text{(2d):}$ $\frac1{2i}z-\frac1{2i}\bar z=\Im(z)$
$\text{(2e):}$ $\Im\left(\log\left(1-\frac12i\right)\log(1+i)\right)$
$\phantom{\text{(2e):}}$ $=\frac\pi8\log\left(\frac54\right)-\frac\pi4\log(2)+\frac12\log(2)\tan^{-1}(2)$
$\text{(2f):}$ evaluate

Comment: Splendid! It took me a while to understand your solution, but you overkilled as always... Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Using first $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{(x+i)(x-i)}=\frac i 2\left(\frac{1}{x+i}-\frac{1}{x-i}\right)$$
Assuming $a>b>0$
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(a-b x)}{x+i}\,dx=-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{a+i
   b}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a-b}{a+i b}\right)-\log (a)
   \log \left(\frac{i b}{a+i b}\right)+$$ $$\log (a-b) \log
   \left(\frac{(1+i) b}{a+i b}\right)$$ Doing the smae for the second and recombining all pieces
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(a-b x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\log (a) \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)-\log (a-b) \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{a-b}{a+b}\right)+$$
$$\frac i 2\left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{a-i
   b}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a-b}{a-i
   b}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{a+i
   b}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a-b}{a+i b}\right)\right)$$

For $a=2$ and $b=1$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(2-x)}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x=\log (2) \tan ^{-1}(2)+$$ $$\frac i 2 \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{4+2i}{5} \right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{4-2i}{5} \right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{2-i}{5}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left
   (\frac{2+i}{5}\right)\right)$$

Inverse symbolic calculators do not find what is
$$-0.43232421462851709114401308429334124864499857979115\cdots$$

Comment: How you proved right hand side of $\int_0^1 \frac{\log(a-bx)}{x+i} \, ?$ I will try this method to find closed form of $\mathcal{J}$